# One hour layover LAX domestic flights

Tags: short-connections, lax

Checking to see if a one-hour layover is enough time, flying JetBlue from Newark to LAX, code share flight on Hawaiian from LAX to HNL. Would all be on one ticket and bags checked through, but I've never done a connection this short. I always leave more time for any possible problems. Never been to LAX so I don't know the layout of the airport at all.

Comment: JetBlue doesn't operate any nonstop flights from Newark to LA. Do you have another connection somewhere, like Boston or Fort Lauderdale?

Comment: Sorry, I am leaving from JFK

Answer (score 1):

Airport not withstanding, if the airline sells you such a connection, they expect you to make it.  If the inbound flight is notably delayed, they will reaccommodate you on a later HNL flight.

Presumably, you will arrive and depart at Terminal 5 which is relatively small.  You will not have to pass TSA again.

Comment: @choster Yes, bah, not even a month ago and I was just there. :(  You can remove the DV now.  Answer updated.  Thanks.